# calling parameters by name in dynet

Tags: neural-network, nlp, dynet

Is there a way to call a parameter by its name in dynet:

```
def dosomething(model):
    temp = model.get_parameter("temp") #something like this?
    ...

def create():
    Model = ParameterCollection()
    temp = Model.add_parameters((2,2))
    ...
    dosomething(Model)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do so directly, using dynet API.

Each parameter has a name, that you can specify with the keyword argument `name`. Example:

```
pW = model.add_parameter((12, 12), name="W")
```

However ([source](http://dynet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python_ref.html#dynet.ParameterCollection)):

> The names are used for identifying the parameters and the collection hierarchy when loading from disk, and in particular when loading only a subset of the objects in a saved file.
>
> ...
>
> One can supply an optional informative name when creating the parameter or sub-collection. The supplied names are then appended with running index to avoid name clashes.

So you cannot retrieve the corresponding parameter based on the `ParameterCollection` object and the name (well, you could but I would not advise it).

---

So the usual practice to achieve when you need is to use a dictionary:

```
import dynet as dy

def dosomething(model, params):
    pW = params["W"]
    pb = params["b"]
    #...

def create():
    model = dy.ParameterCollection()
    params = {}
    params["W"] = model.add_parameters((12, 12))
    params["b"] = model.add_parameters((12, ))

    #...
    dosomething(model, params)

create()
```